# Htacces - redirecting selected

Tags: .htaccess

I have 2 domains (domain1.com and domain2.com).

I want to make such redirects:

a) few specific subpages in domain1.com redirect to specific subpages in domain2.com

b) other subpages from domain1.com redirect to specific subpage in domain2.com .

My htacces dont work propoerly. What i can change in this htacces?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule domain1.com/a http://domain2.com/ssd [R=301,L]
RewriteRule domain1.com/ad http://domain2.com/ssw [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match domain name in `RewriteRule`.

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^a(/.*)?$ http://domain2.com/ssd [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ad(/.*)?$ http://domain2.com/ssw [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com [R=301,L,NC]
```